# Package colord being held back due to wrong version of libsane-common

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dependencies, sane

Running `sudo apt upgrade` reports

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libieee1284-3:i386
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages have been kept back:
  colord
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

leading me to think that something is broken.  It appears that this package depends on libsane1, but attempting to install it gives the following error message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libsane1 : Depends: libsane-common (= 1.0.27-1~experimental3ubuntu2) but 1.0.27+git20190324-xenial0 is to be installed
            Recommends: sane-utils (>= 1.0.27-1~experimental3ubuntu2)
```

Attempting to install the right version directly with `sudo apt install libsane-common=1.0.27-1~experimental3ubuntu2` gives

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libsane1_1.0.27-1~experimental3ubuntu2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsane.so.1.0.27', which is also in package libsane:amd64 1.0.27+git20190324-xenial0
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
```

I also was going to try uninstalling and reinstalling libsane-common, but `sudo apt remove libsane-common --dry-run` prints

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  colord-data libcolord-gtk1 libcolorhug2 libieee1284-3 libieee1284-3:i386 libnss-myhostname
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  colord gnome-control-center libsane libsane-common ubuntu-desktop
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 5 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Remv ubuntu-desktop [1.417]
Remv gnome-control-center [1:3.28.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2]
Remv colord [1.2.12-1ubuntu1]
Remv libsane [1.0.27+git20190324-xenial0]
Remv libsane-common [1.0.27+git20190324-xenial0]
```

which seems rather dangerous, as it would uninstall ubuntu-desktop and gnome-control-center for some strange reason.  Is there a way that I can fix this without potentially breaking my entire installation?

Edit: The commands `sudo apt autoremove` and `sudo apt clean` ran without errors.  Running `sudo apt install colord` gives the error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 colord : Depends: libsane1 (>= 1.0.24) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Run these commands one at a time `sudo apt autoremove`, `sudo apt clean`, `sudo apt install colord` post any errors you may get here.

Comment: @Parto Done, see my edit above.

Answer (score 4):

I eventually took a leap of faith and fixed the problem by running

```
sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends libsane libsane-common
```

to forcibly remove the offending packages without uninstalling any core Ubuntu packages, and then

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

fixed everything for me.

Comment: `--fix-broken` solved it